# Getting loop with Socket.Io Listeners

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a server developed with NodeJS, Socket.IO and Express. I developed a website to deal against that server and works all fine. The trouble comes when I tried to develop an android application.

I have a method on socket.io that returns an array of objects with. In code is like:

```
socket.on("getData",function(data){
 if(data!=null){
 io.sockets.connected.emit("getSocData", {result:true});
}
}
```

In the client, in js, where is working fine.

```
socket.on("getSocData", function (data) {
 if(data){alert("good"); }
}
```

The trouble comes when I debug the Android app, where the code is:

```
mSocket.on("getSocData", new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object.. args) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When I debug that Android code with my mobile, start looping the run method more than 20 times, although the mSocket.on only is triggering one time.

I am getting crazy because in website is working fine but in Android freezes the app until the run method stop.

The dependecy that I use is:

```
compile ('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

Thx 4 all guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before set event listeners for your socket call `off()` method so you clear all attached events:

```
mSocket.off()
mSocket.on("getSocData", new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object.. args) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm!! I thought client in android and in website works similar.